# System (Samsung galaxy book 2) goes to sleep cycle while installing Ubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, samsung

I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.10 on my samsung galaxy book 2 device (i7-1255U) using USB bootable device but once i hit install or try ubuntu after some time screen goes dark and after hitting any key the screen lights up and then goes dark again in some kind of sleep loop.. to get out of it i have to force shutdown the system..

I tried using ubuntu 22.04.2 too, even tried linuxmint21.1, also tried changing from rufus to etcher still same issue

there is no error in my bootable device i have checked it all thoroughly kindly help me out.

Thank you!

Comment: Your question lacks detail. Where is the version of Ubuntu? Where have you documented the steps you have done and any errors you got?. What is partition of memory? Partition is a hard disk term and has nothing to do with memory. Any help you get is as good as the info in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a Galaxy Book 2 (750XED) with Ubuntu installed on it, though I'm currently using 23.04 instead of 22.10.

The issue with the black screen once X starts is due to the i915 driver and drm. You can switch to a console (ctrl+alt+F2), log in and examine `dmesg` to see this.

You can work around it by passing the `nomodeset` parameter to the kernel, but you will have poor 3d performance, functions like adjusting the backlight won't work and various ACPI functions have issues too (e.g., KDE's shutdown or reboot buttons don't work properly, though calling `sudo reboot` in a console does).